# Update Json file from Python script

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file with this format :

> {
> "list": [
> {
> "key1" : "value1",
> "key2" : "value2"
> },
> {
> "key1" : "value1",
> "key2" : "value2"
> }
> ]
> }

I need to read all items of my file and update the key2 but new value.
My issus that my script create new item and not update the current.

```
list= open('file.json','r+')
data = json.load(list)
for item in data['list']:
 item.update(key2="newValue")
 json.dump(item,list)
list.close
```

I want the result like this :

> {
> "list": [
> {
> "key1" : "value1",
> "key2" : "newValue"
> },
> {
> "key1" : "value1",
> "key2" : "newValue"
> }
> ]
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to read the file and close it. Then update the structure, then write it back to the file. These are the three steps:

```py
with open('file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data['list']:
    item.update(key2="newValue")

with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```